# How is getContinueShoppingUrl() called by Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')?

Tags: magento-1.9, link, methods, singleton, inheritance

I'm using **Magento 1.9** and am trying to gain a better understanding of the method, `getContinueShoppingUrl()`, when called by `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')` but can't seem to find the file that defines the method.  Tracing through class inheritance, this is what I've got:

**core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Session.php:**

```
class Mage_Checkout_Model_Session extends Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract
{
    /* getContinueShoppingUrl() not defined */
}
```

**core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php:**

```
class Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract extends Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien
{
    /* getContinueShoppingUrl() not defined */
}
```

**core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php:**

```
class Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien extends Varien_Object
{
    /* getContinueShoppingUrl() not defined */
}
```

**lib/Varien/Object.php:**

```
class Varien_Object implements ArrayAccess
{
    /* getContinueShoppingUrl() not defined */
}
```

So how does `getContinueShoppingUrl` get called by `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')?`  The only place that I found a definition for the method was in `core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart.php` but the `getContinueShoppingUrl()` method in `class Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart` is where I started the trace for: `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getContinueShoppingUrl(true);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`continue_shopping_url` is a session variable. You can set the session value for this variable.

The session value is set here
[Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart::getContinueShoppingUrl()](https://github.com/rmsundar1/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart.php#L133-L144)

```
public function getContinueShoppingUrl()
{
   $url = $this->getData('continue_shopping_url');
    if (is_null($url)) {
      $url = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getContinueShoppingUrl(true);
      if (!$url) {
        $url = Mage::getUrl();
       }
       $this->setData('continue_shopping_url', $url);
   }
   return $url;
}
```

To get better understanding for the set and get session value refer this [link](https://www.apptha.com/blog/how-to-set-retrieve-and-unset-session-variables-in-magento/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, Meenakshi.  Just so confirm my understanding, is Magento using dynamically named methods for setting and getting session variables?  Looking at `Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php`, the `start()` method calls `call_user_func_array('session_set_cookie_params', $cookieParams);`

Answer (score 0):

getContinueShoppingUrl is defined in two places:

**app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart.php**

```
public function getContinueShoppingUrl()
{
    $url = $this->getData('continue_shopping_url');
    if (is_null($url)) {
        $url = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getContinueShoppingUrl(true);
        if (!$url) {
            $url = Mage::getUrl();
        }
        $this->setData('continue_shopping_url', $url);
    }
    return $url;
}
```

**app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Failure.php**

```
public function getContinueShoppingUrl()
    {
        return Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart');
    }
```